# In Ansible how to filter list and non-list data in loop

Tags: ansible

Assuming data shown below, how to loop over interface.name that have family-name=ipv4 ?
Is it possible using only builtin filters ?

Please notice that address-family is a mapping or list of mappings (it seems to be my problem).
I tried a few ideas but got nowhere close to the solution.

```
    "interface": [
    {
        "address-family": {
            "family-name": "ipv4"
        },
        "name": "eth0.1033500",
    },
    {
        "address-family": {
            "family-name": "ipv6"
        },
        "name": "eth0.1033900",
    },
    {
        "address-family": [
            {
                "family-name": "ipv4",
            },
            {
                "family-name": "ipv6"
            }
        ],
        "name": "eth0.1034000",
    }
]
```

Comment: please have a look at the filter `json_query()`

Comment: @TRW I'd be happy to get an example of how you managed to handle the above case with `json_query` because I have absolutely no idea myself. How do you cope with that `address_familly` attribute being once a dict and the other a list of dicts to filter the data ?

Comment: I've played with jmespath.org a little bit and come up with query `interface[*].{n: name, f: map(&family-name, [address-family][])}[?contains(f,'ipv4')]`. It fixes dist/list inconsistency.  I've not tried in Ansible yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not consistent. *address-family* in the first two items is a dictionary, but it's a list in the third one. (Better readable in YAML)

```yaml
interface:
  - address-family:
      family-name: ipv4
    name: eth0.1033500
  - address-family:
      family-name: ipv6
    name: eth0.1033900
  - address-family:
      - family-name: ipv4
      - family-name: ipv6
    name: eth0.1034000
```

If you're looking for an attribute "*that have family-name=ipv4*" the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ interface|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?\"address-family\".\"family-name\"=='ipv4'].name"
```

gives

```yaml
  item: eth0.1033500
```

If you're looking for an item in the list "*that have family-name=ipv4*" the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ interface|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?\"address-family\"[?\"family-name\"=='ipv4']].name"
```

gives

```yaml
  item: eth0.1034000
```

---

Concatenate the results of the queries to iterate both "*list and non-list data in the loop*". For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ interface|json_query(query1) +
                interface|json_query(query2) }}"
      vars:
        query1: "[?\"address-family\".\"family-name\"=='ipv4'].name"
        query2: "[?\"address-family\"[?\"family-name\"=='ipv4']].name"
```

gives

```yaml
  item: eth0.1033500
  item: eth0.1034000
```